# Installing Leiningen on Arch Linux fails due to PGP signing issue

Tags: clojure, leiningen, archlinux

I'm trying to install Leiningen 1:2.6.1-3 on my Antergos / Arch linux laptop.

When using 

`yaourt -S leiningen`

I receive the following pgp signing error:

```
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    2.6.1.tar.gz ... Passed
    leiningen-2.6.1-standalone.zip ... Passed
    leiningen-2.6.1-standalone.zip.asc ... Skipped
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    leiningen-2.6.1-standalone.zip ... FAILED (unknown public key   5A92E04305696D78)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build leiningen.
```

==> Restart building leiningen ? [y/N]

I've tried to enable `auto-key-retrieve` through uncommenting the applicable line in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` but still receive this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gpg --recv-key 5A92E04305696D78
```

will solve your issue.

Comment: It did. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea why manually importing the key works, while `auto-key-retrieve` doesn't? I'm having the same problem with the `dropbox` package from the AUR right now, and I would really like to get it to work with `auto-key-retrieve`. The config checks out, which I verified with other AUR packages: **some** keys seem to be automatically fetched during verification, and some don't. :/